Is there a syntax for varargs splicing compatible with both Scala 2 and Scala 3?
Context
One of the differences between Scala 2 and Scala 3 is the syntax for varargs splices.
So given
def combine(strings: String*): Unit = {
  println(strings.mkString("; "))
}

val list = List("a", "b")

In Scala 2 one can call the function with:
combine((list ++ list): _*)

In Scala 3 the syntax is:
combine((list ++ list)*)

Question
If I want to write code which compiles and works in both Scala 2 and Scala 3, what are the syntax options, if I want to continue to use varargs?
I know I can define the argument type to be Seq[String] instead, but that's giving up the varargs convenience.
Assume I can change both the method definition and call sites.

You can use -Xsource:3 (possibly with -Xsource-feature, or with -Xsource:3-cross instead) in scalacOptions for Scala 2.
Then:
combine((list ++ list)*)

would compile in both Scala 2 and Scala 3.

You can use -Xsource:3 as advised in another answer, or you can use Scala 2 syntax. It is deprecated in Scala 3.4, but it still works (and it works without any reservations in 3.3 and below).
If you need to cross-compile with 3.4 and want to disable the warning temporarily, you can add following to scalacOptions:
    scalacOptions += "-Wconf:msg=is no longer supported for vararg splices:s"

